# finding point in SVG after transform

Tags: svg, raphael, transformation

I have a set of paths that i have created a geographical map with in inkscape and used Raphael to put on a webpage. When i load them through Raphael i am applying a transform so that the map fills the available space.

something similar to this :-

size = "s2,2,0,0";

translate = "t90,45";

countries.transform(translate + size); // countries are basically a set of paths

Now, when i click on the map i get an XY point. I want to save these coordinates so that each click corresponds to the original coordinate space BEFORE i transformed the map. i.e. i want to apply a reverse transformation so that the points i clicked would appear in their proper position if the map had not been transformed when loaded.

Can anyone tell me how to apply this transformation (this one specifically or in general to any applied transformation) so i can preserve the positions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generic solution:

```
function getOriginalPt (x, y, element) {
    var matrix = element.matrix.invert(),
        x1 = x * matrix.a + y * matrix.b + matrix.e,
        y1 = x * matrix.c + y * matrix.d + matrix.f;
    return {x: x1, y: y1};
}

// USAGE
var paper = Raphael(0, 0, 500, 400),
    rect = paper.rect(10, 50, 100, 100).transform('t50,90s2,2,15,30t200,-50'),
    bBox = rect.getBBox(),
    originalPt = getOriginalPt(bBox.x, bBox.y, rect);
```

Specific solution:

Let (x1, y1) be the point to preserve.

```
var pt = {x: x1, y: y1},
    scaleOrigin = {x: 0, y: 0},
    scale = {x: 2, y: 2},
    translate = {x: 90, y: 45};
// EDITED
pt.x = (pt.x - scaleOrigin.x - translate.x) / scale.x + scaleOrigin.x;
pt.y = (pt.y - scaleOrigin.y - translate.y) / scale.y + scaleOrigin.y;
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: @Alex ainsworth, Have revamped the answer with a generic solution that works in general for any set of transformations.

Comment: Thanks NRC explains it nicely

Comment: @AlexAinsworth, Happy to help. However, since you are new to StackOverflow (as evident from your profile), I would like to make you aware of (if not yet) the concept of up-voting the answer you like most or satisfy your need. It helps us earn a few more rewarding points, who takes the interest in answering. Help us build the community stronger. Hope you don't mind. :)

Comment: I'm not sure but I think x & y should be calculated like this:
x1 = x * matrix.a + y * matrix.c + matrix.e,
y1 = x * matrix.b + y * matrix.d + matrix.f;

Answer (score 0):

you have to invert the current transform matrix:

```
_element_.getCTM().inverse();
```

shold provide you with a transformation matrix representing the inversion of all transforms applied to `_element_`. this method does not relate to raphael specifically.

note: by spec, didn't test it myself.

Comment: To my knowledge, Raphael can only transform an element. So, in this case, transforming a full path may be expensive and not necessary.

Answer (score 0):

I have put together a simple function:

```
// point: SVGPoint
// element: The element containing the point
function getTransformedPoint(point, element) {
  const matrix = element.getCTM().inverse();
  return point.matrixTransform(matrix);
}
```

I have made a simple example on this [pen](https://codepen.io/netsi1964/pen/eYdZVob) with an example of a circle animated using CSS animation and using the above code to get the actual transformed position.